# Create a bulletin board on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan, enumerize

It is necessary to write a bulletin board with the division of ads by category (the ad can be in different categories at the same time).
Ads must have several statuses (moderation / approved / rejected), only the administrator can change the status.

Tell me what fields in the model do I need to create for the ad table and categories? And how do I tie them together?

Thankful in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# app/models/advert.rb
class Advert < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  enum status: [:moderation, :approved, :rejected]
end

# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :adverts
end
```

You need to have [a **JOINS** table](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table), to link the two tables. By rails convention, this will be called `adverts_categories` (but it's easy to override if preferred).

The database migrations to create these tables could, for example, be:

```
class CreateAdverts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :adverts do |t|
      t.integer :status
      # ...
    end
  end
end

class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      # (What fields does this table have?)
      t.string :name
      # ...
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdvertsCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :adverts, :categories do |t|
      t.index :advert_id
      t.index :category_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: StackOverflow is an English website; please try to avoid Russian! (I put your comment through a translator, though...)

Comment: Sorry, Tom.
Thanks) Can the declaration table create a field: category_id, and for the Category field: advert_id? I understand it is necessary to create an API?

Comment: The `create_joins_table` will create the `category_id` and `advert_id` columns in the JOIN table as needed. Because it's a **has_and_**belongs_to_many association, there is no `category_id` field in the `adverts` table.

Comment: Thanks, Tom)I'll try to implement it.

Comment: As for the API... I don't know what you want to build. Your question does not say. But most likely yes, you will need some sort of an API. This will consist of the `routes.rb`, controller actions, and possibly views/serializers -- depending on what you're trying to achieve. I suggest you go through a rails tutorial to get started :)

Comment: Now I'll update the condition a bit so that it's clear.

Comment: Are you now asking how to build an entire website?! Is this a job interview question? Sorry, but this is *way* too broad for a StackOverflow post; you'll need to have a go at each part for yourself and ask more specific, narrow questions if stuck.

Comment: I'm not asking you to help with the whole task! I wrote this because you did not understand the essence of the application!!!!I was slandered just in vain! What will others think now because of you.